# Nexus 2 Repository Manager web failed to start

Tags: repository, nexus, sonatype, artifact

I have downloaded and installed Nexus 2 according to official guide.
Then run it. Nothing strange can't see in log files. 
But when I can try to get web interface http://apphost:9990/nexus/, I see on the web page:

```
Directory: /nexus/

LICENSE.html    12043 bytes     May 31, 2017 7:39:55 AM 
WEB-INF/    4096 bytes  May 31, 2017 7:39:55 AM 
favicon.ico     1150 bytes  May 31, 2017 7:39:49 AM 
favicon.png     1179 bytes  May 31, 2017 7:39:49 AM 
images/ 4096 bytes  May 31, 2017 7:39:55 AM 
robots.txt  86 bytes    May 31, 2017 7:39:49 AM
```

It seems Java is not running correctly, because it shows just static content.
 [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyUV6.png)

Java is installed:

```
[opt]$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

Nexus home:

```
echo $NEXUS_HOME
/opt/nexus
```

Log file:

```
jvm 1    | 2017-06-01 05:20:43,496-0700 DEBUG [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.NxApplication - Started
jvm 1    | 2017-06-01 05:20:43,496-0700 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.webapp.WebappBootstrap - Initialized
jvm 1    | 2017-06-01 05:20:43,552-0700 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.InstrumentedSelectChannelConnector - Metrics enabled
jvm 1    | 2017-06-01 05:20:43,570-0700 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started InstrumentedSelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9990
jvm 1    | 2017-06-01 05:20:43,570-0700 INFO  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Running
jvm 1    | 2017-06-01 05:20:43,570-0700 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Started
jvm 1    | 2017-06-01 05:20:47,915-0700 DEBUG [HC4x-EvictingThread] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.apachehttpclient.Hc4ProviderImpl$ManagedClientConnectionManager - Closing expired connections
jvm 1    | 2017-06-01 05:20:47,916-0700 DEBUG [HC4x-EvictingThread] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.apachehttpclient.Hc4ProviderImpl$ManagedClientConnectionManager - Closing connections idle longer than 30000 MILLISECONDS
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: What have you tried so far? What drives you to the conclusion to say "Java is not running correctly"? Maybe you should read this to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Markus Thank you for reply. Trying to provide more information. That is my 1st question here.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue. 
I guess archive was corrupted. 
Nexus were successfully run after complete reinstall.